# How to use Mobile web to control desktop web page

Tags: html, websocket, mobile-website

I'm new in Web Develop, I wish to made a web page URL that ask user to launch in mobile and can control the Web page.

For example, user visit at www.abc.com, and it will ask user use mobile to access g.it.com
and there is 3 buttons. So user might choose the 1st button and at desktop will show 1st layout.

I had try on websocket but I have no idea how to made it.

Need Help!!!

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the demo at https://demo.crossbar.io/videocontrol/ and then take a look at the code on github https://github.com/crossbario/crossbardemo/tree/master/web/demo/videocontrol - this controls a video player in one browser tab via another browser tab, e.g. on mobile. (Plus launching the mobile page is via QR code, which is neat.)

Comment: wow..is cool. will try on the server setup thank @gzost

Comment: @gzost hello the dome is down ?